# Return an array of directories from glob function

Tags: php

I'm trying to return an array of directories available inside another directory from a single line of code without execute the foreach. For do this I actually use this code logic:

```
$dirs = array();
foreach(array_filter(glob('main_dir/language/*'), 'is_dir') as $dir)
{
    $dirs[] = basename($dir);
}
```

now the problem's that I should have another array called `$dirs` and push the directory name inside it, I'm looking for a solution in one line that return an array, something like this:

```
return array_filter(glob('main_dir/language/*'), 'is_dir')
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` function:

```
return json_encode(array_map('basename', array_filter(glob('main_dir/language/*'), 'is_dir')));
```

And then you can get the array with the `json_decode` function.

Comment: but for return only the basename?

Comment: Try it, and if you resolve your problem you can make your question as resolved.

Comment: this working only in one part, I need to return only the basename of each directory as my post described.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to extract directories, [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) has a setting for that...

```
$dirs=glob('main_dir/language/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

If you want to remove the path:

```
$dirs=array_map('basename',glob('main_dir/language/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

---

Or even better, just change your current working directory before calling `glob()`:

```
chdir('main_dir/language/');
$dirs=glob('*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```